# Detect macOS beta using script

Tags: macos, command-line, script, beta

In a shell script, how can I tell whether or not the script is running on a (public) beta version of macOS?

Preferrably, I would like to check this without matching a specific version of macOS, since even though macOS 12 Monterey, is beta right now, it won't be in the future.

Comment: To clarify: you're looking for some sort of flag/marker that identifies any given OS version as a beta, rather than a public release? So your script would identify betas of Catalina and Mojave, if someone is still running those, as well as betas of MacOS 15 "Vasquez Rocks" from the future?
Can I ask what the script does?

Comment: @benwiggy yes. The scenario is that I'm running a setup script that runs Homebrew. I run the same script on several computers. The ‘brew doctor‘ command reports warnings when running on beta and I want to ignore warnings only in that instance.

Comment: A quick read of [https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh) it sets `MACOS_NEWEST_UNSUPPORTED="12.0"` and ascertains the _version_ by `/usr/bin/sw_vers -productVersion` which I'll assume on **macOS Monterey** it's currently returning `12.0`. So maybe using a local copy of `install.sh` and editing it, changing `12.0` to `13.0`, then use the local copy to install from would work. Don't know for sure, just spit balling, I have yet to play with **macOS Monterey** to test this.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just not install Homebrew where it isn't supported?

Comment: @MarcWilson in experience so far, homebrew works ok on Monterey

Comment: What do you want to do if you have a beta version of a minor version e.g. a recent beta of 11.5 or in a few months 12.1?

Comment: I would have thought that warnings on betas are really the most important to catch. As a member of the beta program you should be reporting these issues to Apple, this is the reason Apple gave you access or privately to Homebrew

Comment: I doubt he has access to a beta of Homebrew.  HB 3.2.0 supposedly has support for Monterey, but if you read the PR all that brings is for it to supposedly be able to install Big Sur packages, it still natters about HB not supporting a beta OS.

Comment: While a given version of MacOS is not a reliable indicator of the installation being a beta or a release, the BuildVersion may work better. Though I don't think there is anything inherent of all beta versions that is detectable, I think your best bet would be using the BuildVersion and a lookup table.

Comment: It wouldn't be hard to collect all the BuildVersion(s) of release builds, installinstallmacosx.py displays them, for example.

Comment: Maybe `sw_vers` will give something if it's beta or not.